# How can I pass the text of a string as name of a continue label?

Tags: java, groovy

What I want to do is to pass the text of a string as name of a continue label. Something like this:

```
def scenario(String status) {   
    switch (status) {
        case "labelOne": continue labelOne; break
        case "labelTwo": continue labelTwo; break
        case "labelThree": continue labelThree; break
    }   
    labelOne:
    // Code...
    labelTwo:
    // Code...
    labelThree:
    // Code...
}

def fooOne() {
    scenario("labelOne")
}

def fooTwo() {
    scenario("labelTwo")
}

def fooThree() {
    scenario("labelThree")
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can't do this in Java AFAIK...side note: In Java, strings are compared using the `equals()` method, _not_ with `==`.

Comment: Sorry it was a syntax error...

Comment: What you are trying to do is not canonical Java.

Comment: You could use a switch statement with "PosOne" and "PosTwo" as cases. Then loop around to the top of the switch statement.

Comment: @khelwood I have already try this. It is a "scenario" of some calls and if I do this using `switch` I'll have to do many repeats in every `case`!!!

Comment: Then why would that not also happen with your labelled continues?

Comment: @khelwood please take a look at my question I updated my example...

Comment: My suggestion was that you use switch cases _instead_ of your labels.

Comment: @khelwood I can't do that in this case. If I use switch instead of labels I'll have to repeat the same code five or six times. Those labels are part of a "serial" scenario of 60 calls...